# deque iterator OGRE

Tags: c++, iterator, deque, ogre

ok si have i have the following code:

```
for(deque<Ogre::Vector3>::iterator iter(mWalkList.begin()); iter != mWalkList.end() ;  iter++){
            String tmpstr="Knot"+Ogre::StringConverter::toString(n);
            ent = mSceneMgr->createEntity(tmpstr, "knot.mesh");
            tmpstr = "Knot"+Ogre::StringConverter::toString(n)+"Node";
            node = mSceneMgr->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode(tmpstr,*iter);
            node->attachObject(ent);
            node->setScale(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
            n++;
        }
```

But visual studio gives me a error when i hover hover `iterator iter` which says the following: `Error: class "Ogre::deque<Ogre::Vector3, Ogre::STLAllocator<Ogre::Vector3, Ogre::GeneralAllocPolicy>>" has no member 'iterator'`

what am i doing wrong,

sorry im new to Ogre and C++ for that matter, Its a school project so i would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `std::deque<Ogre::Vector3>` instead of `deque<Ogre::Vector3>` (which is `Ogre::deque<Ogre::Vector3>` in this case).

Or you can use `Ogre::deque<Ogre::Vector3>::type`. The docs seem to say that is the same as the `std::deque` above.

Comment: thnx that does the trick... Its weird actually why my teacher would give this code to me.. While it doesnt even work :S

Comment: The error you had was very subtle. I think many (if not most) programmers wouldn't realize there was an error in that code until they tried to compile it. The error has to do with argument-dependant name lookup (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup), which I would consider an advanced topic in C++.

Comment: This is avoided if you don't use `using std` and have the habit of prefixing your stuff with `std::`